# Error when using multiprocessing module in python

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing

I have a problem with use torch.multiprocessing modules.

In my code,

```py
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

class MultiProcessing:
     def run_inference(self):
          # Load detection model
          model = MyModel()
          ...
          processes = []
          for process_idx in range(2):
               p = mp.Process(target=self.do_detection, args=(model, ))
               p.start()  # Error here
               processes.append(p)
          for p in processes:
               p.join()

     def do_detection(self, model):
          vid_cap = cv2.VideoCapture("<VideoFile>")
          while True:
               # Read video
               _, img = vid_cap.read()
               # Input video frame to detection model
               pred = model(img)
               # Visualize detection result
               ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
     inference = MultiProcessing()
     inference.run_inference()
```

Error like below

```py
THCudaCheck FAIL file=..\torch/csrc/generic/StorageSharing.cpp line=249 error=801 : operation not supported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\conda\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\conda\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\conda\lib\site-packages\torch\multiprocessing\reductions.py", line 247, in reduce_tensor
    event_sync_required) = storage._share_cuda_()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (801) : operation not supported at ..\torch/csrc/generic/StorageSharing.cpp:249
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\conda\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

To solve this problem, I search many solutions.
Most solutions say set the `num_worker=0` in dataloader, but i’m not using dataloader.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: you cannot use multiprocessing with cuda on windows with pytorch.  https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html#cuda-ipc-operations

Comment: @Aaron thank you for your reply. i have more questions. Fortunately, i solve the problem by editing code like this link. But i have encountered another problem. would you please see it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70874403/cpu-usage-too-high-when-multiple-inference-using-multiprocessing-in-torch